# When I do a POST, the data is not saved in MongoDB, only _ID is saved

Tags: express, mongoose

I wanted to save data in MongoDB.  I use an open schema (no restrictions). If I do a POST request, only _ID is saved. I get no errors, but the data which I am passing is ignored.

I am new to mongoose. I read docs but could not pinpoint where I am making a mistake.

my Schema:

```
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var product = new Schema({any: {}});
var Product = mongoose.model('Product',product)
```

my POST request:

```
app.post('/input',function(request,response) {
    var product = new Product(request.body);    
    product.save(function(err,saved) {
        if (err) {
            response.send({error:"could not save"});
        } else  {
            response.send(saved);
        }
    })
})
```

What is getting save in MongoDB:

```
{
    "_id": "5ca8c6ada7827b6f64c603bf",
    "__v": 0
}
```

My input:

```
{
    "name":"xmen",
    "age":25
}
```

Please let me know if any other details are required.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing `request.body` to your constructor.`request.body` in your code is an object with 2 propreties : `name: "xmen"` and `age: 25`. 
However your `Schema` contains only one proprety: `any: {}` (`{}` means you accept any data type).
when you pass `request.body` to `var product = new Product(request.body);` you're passing an object with 2 propreties to a constructor that expects an object with one proprety named `any`, so when the constructor doesn't find it returns an object with only an `_id`.
if you provide :

```
  { any:"xmen"}
```

or

```
  {
    any: {
      "name":"xmen",
      "age":25
    }
  }
```

you'll get the expected results.

Answer (score 1):

You're experiencing this because your Mongoose schema is not aware of the properties it should store in the document.

You used `any` as a key in your schema definition, which I assume you did because you followed the [SchemaTypes](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html) section in the documentation.

`any` does not mean any property is acceptable. It means that Mongoose is looking for a value with the key of *"any"*, literally. If your request body does not contain such key (and it does not, as it only contains *name* and *age*), it will not be picked up when you save the new object.

What you are experiencing is the expected behaviour of Mongoose.

**Defining the schema**

MongoDB is flexible in its document structures. However, when you define a new schema you must also define all possible properties and their types (you can also use `{}` as a type to support any type - although it is not recommended).

You can define your schema like this:

```
{
    name: String,
    age: Number
}
```

This means that when you call `.save()` for your new object, Mongoose will pick only the specified properties in the schema (as well as `_id` and `__v`, which exist in any schema by default).

---

Read more about Mongoose Schemas [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html).

Answer (score 0):

1. Basically, If you try to check and console log your `req.body` or `request.body` then you may get `undefined`. So, you need to check if you have written this in file or not.

   app.use(express.json())

this is defining your data as json data.

2. This second check is also related to first one, as make sure you have selected JSON as your Body type while making POST request using tools like postman etc.

Both of these worked in my case :)